# Javascript in Chrome not returning same array length as Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am trying to define an array of objects that I can later loop through based on the length property of the array. In Internet Explorer, it works as I would expect, but not in Chrome. Below is a snippet of code that defines the array of objects:

```
var status =
[
    {
        name: 'Open',
        target:
        [
            {
                systemgenerated: 'false',
                internalonly: 'true',
                name: 'Closed'
            },
            {
                systemgenerated: 'true',
                internalonly: 'true',
                name: 'Done'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Pending',
        target:
        [
            {
                systemgenerated: 'false',
                internalonly: 'true',
                name: 'Closed'
            },
            {
                systemgenerated: 'false',
                internalonly: 'true',
                name: 'Open'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

In Internet Explorer, **status.length** returns 2. In Chrome, it returns 31. Based on examples I've seen on Stack, I have tried a few different ways of defining the object to get it to work like an array in Chrome, but have not made any progress. Is there a manner to define this in Chrome that will act like I would expect an array to act?

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome [also returns `2`](https://jsfiddle.net/vvmfeqd8/). There must be something else going on.

Comment: weird, i could replicate the issue, in Chrome with same code, shows 31 in chrome and 2 in IE -  http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJRRgd

Comment: @NagaSaiA That's because jsfiddle wraps the code inside of a window.onload by default, but codepen just puts it at the end of the body, not inside of any function. Meaning in codepen that variable goes on the window object, and from there you can look at cdrini's answer to see what happens next =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strange! Apparently [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is a reserved word in HTML5 which changes the text of the status bar (so it must be a string).

`var status = [];` will overwrite `window.status` if its not in a function. In this case, chrome converts it to a string, which is why you get an error.

Either change the variable name, or wrap everything in a function to create an isolate scope.

```js
var status = [ {}, {} ];
console.log(status);        // "[object Object],[object Object]" in Chrome
console.log(status.length); // 31 in Chrome
```

```js
(function() {
    var status = [ {}, {} ];
    console.log(status);        // the array
    console.log(status.length); // 2
})();
```

Comment: [According to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-window-status), it looks like chrome is in the right: "For historical reasons, the status attribute on the Window object must, on getting, return the last **string** it was set to"

Comment: Thanks very much! I was spinning around in circles trying to figure out what was wrong..